# Same outputs but different conditions a[3] and 3[a]

Tags: c

```
char a[10] = "pqrstuvwxyz";
printf("%s", a[3]);
printf("%s", 3[a]);
```

Both the `printf`s give the same output. Why?

It must be something to do with the way the string is represented in the memory by the C compiler, but what is it?

I would have thought that the offset is multiplied by the size of char, in which case they should give different outputs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/in-c-arrays-why-is-this-true-a5-5a

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because those are equivalent expressions.  Indexing is equivalent to pointer arithmetic.

```
int x[10];
int y = x[1];
// same as (and is converted by the compiler to)...
int y = *(x + 1);
```

Since addition is commutative, it is also the same as...

```
int y = *(1 + x);
```

And...

```
int y = 1[x];
```

---

On a side note, you are invoking undefined behavior by using the `%s` format specifier and passing in a `char`.  `%s` expects a null terminated string, i.e., a pointer to `char` terminated by a null character.  Heed your warnings.

If you want to print a substring in that array, use:

```
printf("%s", a + 3);
// or
printf("%s", &a[3]);
```

Comment: it's not transitivity, but _commutativity_.

Comment: @stefan: I wish I could say this was the first time I have made that particular typo. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `%c` format specifier for `a[3]` as it is a character, not a string.`%s` is used for strings, not individual characters.

As for your question why both have same output, well `Both are Same`!! Both are interpreted as `*(a+3)`.In C you can do it both ways.

And make some corrections to your code:

```
printf("%s", a[3]);
printf("%s", 3[a]);
```

would be

```
printf("%c", a[3]);
printf("%c", 3[a]);
```

To print the whole string , you can use either :

```
printf("%s", a);
```

OR

```
printf("%s", &a[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

In `C` `a[i]` is converted to `*(a+i)` internally. `i[a]` is converted to `*(i+a)`. Array names also act as pointers in c. so `(a+i)` or `(i+a)` give an address (using pointer arithmetic) that is `dereferenced` using `*`